# Wait for all dynamic script-src tags to load before executing addEventListener() function

Tags: javascript

my code:

```
Util = {
    load_css : function(urls){

        for ( var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
            var head = document.head;
            var link = document.createElement("link");

            link.type = "text/css";
            link.rel = "stylesheet";
            link.href = urls[i];
            link.className = 'dynamic-css'

            head.appendChild(link);
        }

        document.querySelector('.dynamic-css').addEventListener('load', event => {
            Template.render();
        })
    },
    load_js : function(urls){

        for ( var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('src', urls[i]);
            script.setAttribute('class', 'dynamic-js');
            script.setAttribute('async', false);
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        }

        document.querySelector('.dynamic-js').addEventListener('load', event => {
            Template.render();
        })
    }
}
```

the urls parameter for load_css and load_js is just an array of urls that I want to load (obviously js urls for load_js and css urls for load_css). Currently, I don't think the addEventListener('load' ...) waits for all items to load; just one. How can I make it wait for all items?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promisify the load listeners and use `Promise.all`.

```
Promise.all(
    urls.map((url) => {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('src', url);
        script.setAttribute('class', 'dynamic-js');
        script.setAttribute('async', false);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            script.addEventListener('load', resolve);
            script.addEventListener('error', reject);
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        });
    })
)
    .then(() => {
        Template.render();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // at least one script had an error
    });
```

Live demo:

```js
const urls = [
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js',
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js'
];

Promise.all(
    urls.map((url) => {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('src', url);
        script.setAttribute('class', 'dynamic-js');
        script.setAttribute('async', false);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            script.addEventListener('load', resolve);
            script.addEventListener('error', reject);
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        });
    })
)
    .then(() => {
        console.log(typeof $);
        console.log(typeof _);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // at least one script had an error
    });
```

Comment: js scripts are still not being loaded before .then() functions are executed. example: jquery is a script that is loaded, but I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when the script tries to execute Template.render()

Comment: See live snippet - it looks to work fine when using example URLs for jQuery and Lodash, both are successfully loaded when the `.then` is entered into

Answer (score 0):

If order matters, this loads each script one at a time in sequence (rather than as a whole batch), which is why they're individual promises vs promiseAll

```
const scripts = [
  "https://somewhere.com/scripts/script1.js",
  "https://somewhere.com/scripts/script2.js",
  "https://somewhere.com/scripts/script3.js",
  "https://somewhere.com/scripts/script4.js"
];

let sctr = 0;
const doScript = () => {
  if (sctr++ >= scripts.length) {
    console.log('all scripts loaded');
    Template.render();
    return;
  }
  const scriptPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;
    script.async = true; // they're loading one at a time, so async is ok
    script.src = scripts[sctr];
  });

  scriptPromise.then(() => {
      console.log(scripts[sctr], 'loaded');
      doScript();
    },
    (err) => {
      console.error(scripts[sctr], 'failed', err);
      // halting
    });
}
```